# Ionic Page Navigation is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Ionic sidemenu default app created and map and markerClick tow page was add ed in menu list. Map is working fine but MarkerClick is not. When click on MarkerClick form sidemenu this redirect on last active page.

menu.html

```
 <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
                Login
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
                Search
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
                Browse
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
                Playlists
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/map">
                Map
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/markerClick">
                Marker
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

app.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.search', {
        url: '/search',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.browse', {
        url: '/browse',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.playlists', {
        url: '/playlists',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
                controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.single', {
        url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
                controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.map', {
        url: '/map',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
                controller: 'MapCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.markerClick', {
        url: '/markerClick',
        view: {
            'menuContent': {
                //templateUrl: '<h1>what the hello</h1>',
                templateUrl: 'templates/testTemplate.html',
                controller: 'markerClickCtr'
            }
        }
    });
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/map');
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wBz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BasGN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace href with ui-sref="app.markerClick"
UI-Router provides ui-sref which allows to link to states. This is different than linking to a normal URL. When using UI-Router you want to link to a state, not a URL.